# Storing data in class level global variables

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `home.dart` class which on build, fetchs an api result and assigns the response as well as the fetched time (DateTime.now()).

here is the StatefulWidget Home class

```dart
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  int maxCacheDurationInMinutes = 2;
  DateTime _lastUpdatedTime;
  Usage previousFetchedUsage;

  @override
  _HomeView createState() => _HomeView();
}
```

on the state, i access the elements using `widget._lastUpdatedTime` like so.
here is the state class and the requesting function

```dart
class _HomeView extends State<HomeView> {
  bool get isValidCache =>
      widget._lastUpdatedTime != null &&
      DateTime.now().difference(widget._lastUpdatedTime).inMinutes <
          widget.maxCacheDurationInMinutes;

  int get minsSinceLastCached => widget._lastUpdatedTime != null
      ? DateTime.now().difference(widget._lastUpdatedTime).inMinutes
      : 0;

  Future<Usage> requestUsage(BuildContext context) async {
    if (isValidCache) {
      // is valid cache

      if (widget.previousFetchedUsage != null) {
        // return cached if it isn't null
        return widget.previousFetchedUsage;
      }
    }

    // if cache is invalid or cache is null
    // fetch the latest data and assign to cache variable
    widget._lastUpdatedTime = DateTime.now();
    return widget.previousFetchedUsage = await ClientHandler.of(context).client.fetchUsage();
  }
}

// some code is omitted to keep it brief
```

The problem here is, on each UI rebuild (during hot reload), the request is send. where technically it only should be send once during the 2 minutes period.
I also tried with make `previousFetchedUsage` as a static variable. still nothing changes.
Is there any concepts i should be aware about in dart ? i am from C# background and recently started with flutter.

Answer (score 0):

your requestUsage is future function and when you use it with FutureBuilder in your ui its never refresh the ui event you fire it in every two minutes.
you can refresh your ui for read the new value with SetState or using Streams in your UI not just FutureBuilder